# Chart Align YAxis to YAxis2

Tags: charts, alignment

I am currently building a chart which has two y axis(left and right). As I plot points on the chart for both axes wrt xaxis, I can see the grid lines in the chart not properly aligned.

Is there any algorithm which by taking the inital point of yaxis and y2 axis and calculates the maximum and minimum values of both axes so that the grid lines in the chart can be aligned properly.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: How are both y axis related? Are you plotting  two functions f[x] and g[x], one wrt each axis?

Comment: Are you using a charting component? Or are you creating the chart just by drawing on the screen yourself?

Comment: I am using visifire chart component.               http://www.visifire.com/silverlight_area_charts_gallery.php